# is present perfect possible here?

Tags: present-perfect

If a project started in the past and is still going on and I have been involved in it from the beginning, could I say that I am proud to have been involved in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can say that. Although, technically, in this position in the sentence, it's not Present Perfect—it's Perfect Infinitive.

Comment: thank you. so it doesn`t necessarily mean the project is finished?

Comment: @anouk First of all, yes, it doesn't necessarily mean that the project is finished (your involvement might have ended, but the project might still be going on). But it's not the main point here. Various re-wordings that result in "to have done/said/been/made" could have, in the previous version of that sentence, been not only in Present Perfect but also in Past Simple. Present Perfect does not necessarily mean something that is still going on. It also means something that is a fact now because of something that happened in the past.

Comment: @anouk The classic example that I use is "I have read a book" means that you have this experience of reading it as part of your intellectual "baggage" now. But it doesn't mean that you are still reading it. Anyway, since what we have in your sentence is a Perfect Infinitive, it could have been transformed from any tense that has any kind of connection to the past.